# Using LocalBroadcastManager for 'sticky' broadcast

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcast

Am I correct in thinking that I cannot send 'sticky' broadcasts using [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) ?
If so this seems very short-sighted particularly if an app uses Fragments that can be swapped in and out during the app lifecycle and relies on broadcast data..

Comment: Sticky broadcasts are now deprecated anyway.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Am I correct in thinking that I cannot send 'sticky' broadcasts using LocalBroadcastManager ?

Yes, you are correct.

> If so this seems very short-sighted particularly if an app uses Fragments that can be swapped in and out during the app lifecycle and relies on broadcast data..

You are welcome to take the source code to `LocalBroadcastManager` and create your own sticky extensions to it, if you so desire. Personally, I would use other means of storing such data (model fragments, singletons, or persistent data stores, depending on scenario).

Comment: I have some fragments on the screen, and I want that depending on what "main" fragment it is loaded, a small fragment on the bottom changes its number. I wanted to do this by sending a broadcast on the main-fragment's onResume. But the fragment that should have displayed the number is not loaded at that point. How can I do this? ....

Comment: @QuadroQ: Have the fragment pull the data from somewhere. Or, switch to an event bus that offers this sort of pattern (greenrobot's EventBus offers sticky events; Square's Otto offers `@Producer`).

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking of Otto!

Answer (score 7):

As @CommonsWare said, I tried to implement sticky with LocalBroadcastManager source codes. Check this:
https://gist.github.com/lidemin/5cd4080ebbc74154a0e7

Not sure whether it is the best way to do that. It works well until now . Personally I prefer using Otto.

```
public class StickyLocalBroadcastManager {

private static class ReceiverRecord {
    final IntentFilter filter;
    final BroadcastReceiver receiver;
    boolean broadcasting;

    ReceiverRecord(IntentFilter _filter, BroadcastReceiver _receiver) {
        filter = _filter;
        receiver = _receiver;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(128);
        builder.append("Receiver{");
        builder.append(receiver);
        builder.append(" filter=");
        builder.append(filter);
        builder.append("}");
        return builder.toString();
    }
}

private static class BroadcastRecord {
    final Intent intent;
    final ArrayList<ReceiverRecord> receivers;

    BroadcastRecord(Intent _intent, ArrayList<ReceiverRecord> _receivers) {
        intent = _intent;
        receivers = _receivers;
    }
}

private static final String TAG = "LocalBroadcastManager";
private static final boolean DEBUG = false;

private final Context mAppContext;

private final HashMap<BroadcastReceiver, ArrayList<IntentFilter>> mReceivers
        = new HashMap<BroadcastReceiver, ArrayList<IntentFilter>>();
private final HashMap<String, ArrayList<ReceiverRecord>> mActions
        = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<ReceiverRecord>>();

private final ArrayList<BroadcastRecord> mPendingBroadcasts
        = new ArrayList<BroadcastRecord>();

private final ArrayList<Intent> mStickyBroadcasts
        = new ArrayList<Intent>();

static final int MSG_EXEC_PENDING_BROADCASTS = 1;

private final Handler mHandler;

private static final Object mLock = new Object();
private static StickyLocalBroadcastManager mInstance;

public static StickyLocalBroadcastManager getInstance(Context context) {
    synchronized (mLock) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new StickyLocalBroadcastManager(context.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return mInstance;
    }
}

private StickyLocalBroadcastManager(Context context) {
    mAppContext = context;
    mHandler = new Handler(context.getMainLooper()) {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case MSG_EXEC_PENDING_BROADCASTS:
                    executePendingBroadcasts();
                    break;
                default:
                    super.handleMessage(msg);
            }
        }
    };
}

/**
 * Register a receive for any local broadcasts that match the given IntentFilter.
 *
 * @param receiver The BroadcastReceiver to handle the broadcast.
 * @param filter   Selects the Intent broadcasts to be received.
 * @see #unregisterReceiver
 */
public void registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver receiver, IntentFilter filter) {
    synchronized (mReceivers) {
        ReceiverRecord entry = new ReceiverRecord(filter, receiver);
        ArrayList<IntentFilter> filters = mReceivers.get(receiver);
        if (filters == null) {
            filters = new ArrayList<IntentFilter>(1);
            mReceivers.put(receiver, filters);
        }
        filters.add(filter);
        for (int i = 0; i < filter.countActions(); i++) {
            String action = filter.getAction(i);
            ArrayList<ReceiverRecord> entries = mActions.get(action);
            if (entries == null) {
                entries = new ArrayList<ReceiverRecord>(1);
                mActions.put(action, entries);
            }
            entries.add(entry);
        }
        //check sticky broadcasts
        for (Intent intent : mStickyBroadcasts) {
            if (mActions.containsKey(intent.getAction())) {
                sendBroadcast(intent, false);
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Unregister a previously registered BroadcastReceiver.  <em>All</em>
 * filters that have been registered for this BroadcastReceiver will be
 * removed.
 *
 * @param receiver The BroadcastReceiver to unregister.
 * @see #registerReceiver
 */
public void unregisterReceiver(BroadcastReceiver receiver) {
    synchronized (mReceivers) {
        ArrayList<IntentFilter> filters = mReceivers.remove(receiver);
        if (filters == null) {
            return;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < filters.size(); i++) {
            IntentFilter filter = filters.get(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < filter.countActions(); j++) {
                String action = filter.getAction(j);
                ArrayList<ReceiverRecord> receivers = mActions.get(action);
                if (receivers != null) {
                    for (int k = 0; k < receivers.size(); k++) {
                        if (receivers.get(k).receiver == receiver) {
                            receivers.remove(k);
                            k--;
                        }
                    }
                    if (receivers.size() <= 0) {
                        mActions.remove(action);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * remove the sticky broadcasts .
 * @param action is the action need to be removed.
 */
public void removeStickyBroadcast(String action) {
    if (action == null || action.length() <= 0) {
        return;
    }
    synchronized (mStickyBroadcasts) {
        Iterator<Intent> intentIterator = mStickyBroadcasts.iterator();
        while (intentIterator.hasNext()) {
            Intent intent = intentIterator.next();
            if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(intent.getAction())) {
                intentIterator.remove();
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * remove all the sticky broadcasts.
 */
public void removeAllStickyBroadcasts(){
    synchronized (mStickyBroadcasts){
        mStickyBroadcasts.clear();
    }
}

/**
 * send broadcast with specified action.
 * @param action is the action .
 * @return
 */
public boolean sendBroadcast(String action){
    Intent intent = new Intent(action);
    return sendBroadcast(intent);
}

/**
 * send broadcast with specified action.
 * @param action is the action .
 * @return
 */
public boolean sendBroadcast(String action, boolean isSticky){
    Intent intent = new Intent(action);
    return sendBroadcast(intent, isSticky);
}

/**
 * Broadcast the given intent to all interested BroadcastReceivers.  This
 * call is asynchronous; it returns immediately, and you will continue
 * executing while the receivers are run.
 *
 * @param intent The Intent to broadcast; all receivers matching this
 *               Intent will receive the broadcast.
 * @see #registerReceiver
 */
public boolean sendBroadcast(Intent intent) {
    return sendBroadcast(intent, false);
}

/**
 * Broadcast the given intent to all interested BroadcastReceivers.  This
 * call is asynchronous; it returns immediately, and you will continue
 * executing while the receivers are run.
 *
 * @param intent   The Intent to broadcast; all receivers matching this
 *                 Intent will receive the broadcast.
 * @param isSticky The flag of this intent is need to be sticky or not.
 * @see #registerReceiver
 */
public boolean sendBroadcast(Intent intent, boolean isSticky) {
    if (isSticky) {
        mStickyBroadcasts.add(intent);
    }
    synchronized (mReceivers) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        final String type = intent.resolveTypeIfNeeded(
                mAppContext.getContentResolver());
        final Uri data = intent.getData();
        final String scheme = intent.getScheme();
        final Set<String> categories = intent.getCategories();

        final boolean debug = DEBUG ||
                ((intent.getFlags() & Intent.FLAG_DEBUG_LOG_RESOLUTION) != 0);
        if (debug) Log.v(
                TAG, "Resolving type " + type + " scheme " + scheme
                        + " of intent " + intent);

        ArrayList<ReceiverRecord> entries = mActions.get(intent.getAction());
        if (entries != null) {
            if (debug) Log.v(TAG, "Action list: " + entries);

            ArrayList<ReceiverRecord> receivers = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < entries.size(); i++) {
                ReceiverRecord receiver = entries.get(i);
                if (debug) Log.v(TAG, "Matching against filter " + receiver.filter);

                if (receiver.broadcasting) {
                    if (debug) {
                        Log.v(TAG, "  Filter's target already added");
                    }
                    continue;
                }

                int match = receiver.filter.match(action, type, scheme, data,
                        categories, "LocalBroadcastManager");
                if (match >= 0) {
                    if (debug) Log.v(TAG, "  Filter matched!  match=0x" +
                            Integer.toHexString(match));
                    if (receivers == null) {
                        receivers = new ArrayList<ReceiverRecord>();
                    }
                    receivers.add(receiver);
                    receiver.broadcasting = true;
                } else {
                    if (debug) {
                        String reason;
                        switch (match) {
                            case IntentFilter.NO_MATCH_ACTION:
                                reason = "action";
                                break;
                            case IntentFilter.NO_MATCH_CATEGORY:
                                reason = "category";
                                break;
                            case IntentFilter.NO_MATCH_DATA:
                                reason = "data";
                                break;
                            case IntentFilter.NO_MATCH_TYPE:
                                reason = "type";
                                break;
                            default:
                                reason = "unknown reason";
                                break;
                        }
                        Log.v(TAG, "  Filter did not match: " + reason);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (receivers != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < receivers.size(); i++) {
                    receivers.get(i).broadcasting = false;
                }
                mPendingBroadcasts.add(new BroadcastRecord(intent, receivers));
                if (!mHandler.hasMessages(MSG_EXEC_PENDING_BROADCASTS)) {
                    mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_EXEC_PENDING_BROADCASTS);
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Like {@link #sendBroadcast(Intent, boolean)}, but if there are any receivers for
 * the Intent this function will block and immediately dispatch them before
 * returning.
 */
public void sendBroadcastSync(Intent intent) {
    if (sendBroadcast(intent, false)) {
        executePendingBroadcasts();
    }
}

private void executePendingBroadcasts() {
    while (true) {
        BroadcastRecord[] brs = null;
        synchronized (mReceivers) {
            final int N = mPendingBroadcasts.size();
            if (N <= 0) {
                return;
            }
            brs = new BroadcastRecord[N];
            mPendingBroadcasts.toArray(brs);
            mPendingBroadcasts.clear();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < brs.length; i++) {
            BroadcastRecord br = brs[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < br.receivers.size(); j++) {
                br.receivers.get(j).receiver.onReceive(mAppContext, br.intent);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Markus Thanks for your advise. First time post answer on Stackoverflow.